# Django modelfield to put in data recursively while iterating over xml tags

Tags: python, django, django-models, xml-parsing, elementtree

This is my model class

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from django.db import models

class olWS(models.Model):
    country=models.CharField(max_length=4)
    comment=models.TextField()
```

And this is how i'm trying to put in values recursively in the model fields while iterating over xml data from django shell.

```
>>> from ol.models import olWS
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> tree=ET.ElementTree(file='data1')
>>> ws=olWS()
>>> for el in tree.iter():
...     if el.tag=='cusotm_var4':
...         ws.country=el.text
...     if el.tag=='comments':
...         ws.comment=el.text
...
>>> ws.save()
>>> ws.id
1
>>> ws.country
'US'
>>> ws.comment
'where are my cds i ordered'
```

and what i'm getting is just a single row been fed in the model.
How can I get all the values being iterated over in the xml data, in modelfields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and save your instances within the loop; you are only assigning values in the loop in your example.

```
for el in tree.iter():
    ws = olWS()
    ws.country = el.text if el.tag == 'custom_var4' else ''
    ws.comment = el.text if el.tag == 'comments' else ''
    ws.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do one model instance for each row, but as the elements doest seem to be children to a object node but flat list, you can save both values to a dict and then save a model once both are set.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have order of `'custom_var_4'` and `'comments'` elements fixed in XML and both are present , you can improve your code as:

```
>>> for el in tree.iter():
...     if el.tag=='cusotm_var4':
...         ws.country=el.text
...     if el.tag=='comments':
...         ws.comment=el.text
...         ws.save()
```

Note: `ws.save()` in second if.

Disclaimer: you need to take care for aberrations like only one element is present etc.

Comment: Looks a bit fragile - If there's no comments, it doesn't get saved, but if it's missing a customvar, and there are comments, it saves with the value of the last customvar? etc...

Comment: @JonClements yes, I'm pointing to save in loop and not suggesting for better xml parsing. However, added disclaimer in answer.